# Static Functions in C++

Tags: c++, function, static

I've read a few posts on here about static functions, but still am running into trouble with implementation.

I'm writing a hardcoded example of Dijkstra's algorithm for finding the shortest path.

Declared in Alg.h:

```
static void dijkstra();
```

Defined in Alg.cpp:

```
static void Alg::dijkstra() { 

//Create Map
Initialize();

//Loop to pass through grid multiple times
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{   
    current=1;  
    while(current!=6)
    {
        //Iterate through and update distances/predecessors
        //For loop to go through columns, while current iterates rows
        for(int j=1; j<7; j++)
        {
            //Check if distance from current to this node is less than
            //distance already stored in d[j] + weight of edge

            if(distanceArray[current][j]+d[current]<d[j])
            {
                //Update distance
                d[j] = distanceArray[current][j]+d[current];
                //Update predecessor
                p[j] = current;
            }    
        }
        //Go to next row in distanceArray[][]
        current++;
    } //End while


} //End for

output();
} //End Dijkstras
```

I want to call my function from main **without an object**. When I had all of this code in Main.cpp, it worked perfectly. Splitting it up into separate files caused  the error `Main.cpp:15: error: ‘dijkstra’ was not declared in this scope`.The posts I came across when searching SE gave me me the impression that to do this, I needed to make that method static, yet I still have no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Alg.h"

int main() { 

    dijkstra();
    return 0; 
}
```

Edit: Added full header file, Alg.h:

```
#ifndef Alg_
#define Alg_

#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

class Alg
{
    public:
        void tracePath(int x);
        void output();
        void printArray();
        void Initialize();
        static void dijkstra();
        int current, mindex;
        int distanceArray[7][7]; //2D array to hold the distances from each point to all others
        int d[6]; //Single distance array from source to points
        int p[6]; //Array to keep predecessors 
        int copyD[6]; //Copy of d[] used for sorting purposes in tracePath()
        int order[6]; //Contains the order of the nodes path lengths in ascending order

}; //End alg class

#endif
```

Original all-in-one working Main.cpp file: http://pastebin.com/67u9hGsL

Comment: Please provide the full context of your header file. I'm guessing that `dijkstra` is supposed to be a class static?

Comment: The definition of a static member function cannot contain the keyword `static`. Your attempt to define `static void Alg::dijkstra() {` will immediately trigger a compile error in `Alg.cpp`. Yet, you report a completely different error. And you claim that this code "worked" in `main.cpp`. This means that you posted fake code. Your claims are unrealistic. Post real code, please.

Comment: What is `Alg`??? Is it a class? Is it a namespace?

Comment: @AndreyT Alg is a class. See the edit.

Comment: @user3063527: Er... The code you linked in pastebin is completely different with regard to the issues in question. There's no `Alg` in that code. There's no `static` in that code.

Comment: @AndreyT Correct, exactly as I stated above. The code works, but I'm now facing errors when trying to separate it into different files. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @user3063527: In that case you have to explain where `Alg` came from and why you are trying to use `static` in the first place. Nothing of that is necessary to just "separate it into different files".

Comment: Asking again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363761/calling-functions-from-main-in-c - big -1 !

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should call it this way:

```
Alg::dijkstra();
```

**Limitations**

- Can't call any other class functions that are not static.
- Can't access non static class data members.
- Can instantiate an object via `new class()` when constructor is private/protected. E.g. a factory function.

Comment: @Johnsyweb That leaves me with a "cannot call member function without object" error.

Comment: Maybe `Initialize()` is not a static function? You cannot call an instance function from a static one because you are not calling it from "inside" an object.

Comment: There's a good chance that `Alg` is a namespace, not a class... However, the OP still hasn't explained what on Earth `Alg` is.

Comment: @egur Thanks, that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 10):

You can just use a namespace instead of having a class with all static members.

Alg.h:

```
namespace Alg
{
   void dijkstra();
}
```

and in Alg.cpp

```
namespace Alg
{
   void dijkstra()
   {
     // ... your code
   }
}
```

in main.cpp

```
#include "Alg.h"

int argc, char **argv)
{
  Alg::dijkstra();

  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure the function is supposed to be static?

It looks as if you want just a function?
in your header file:

```
#ifndef DIJKSTRA_H
#define DIJKSTRA_H
void dijkstra(); 
#endif
```

in your cpp file

```
void dijkstra() {
   /* do something */
}
```

in your main file:

```
#include "yourcppfile.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    dijkstra();
}
```

if you really want a static function you have to put it into a nested class:

```
class Alg {
  public:
    static void dijkstra();
  /* some other class related stuff */
}
```

the implementation somewhere in a cpp file

```
void Alg::dijkstra() {
  /* your code here */
}
```

and then in your cpp file where the main resides

```
#include "your header file.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Alg::dijkstra();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I remember right any 'static' function is limited to the module in which it is implemented. So, 'static' prevents using the function in another module.

Answer (score 2):

In your header file `Alg.h`:

```
#ifndef __ALG_H__
#define __ALG_H__

namespace Alg {

    void dijkstra();

}

#endif
```

The include guards are necessary if you plan to include the header in more than one of your cpp files. It seems you would like to put the function in a namespace `Alg`, right?

In Alg.cpp:

```
#include "Alg.h"

void Alg::dijkstra() { /* your implementation here */ }
```

Then, in main.cpp you call it with full namespace qualification:

```
#include "Alg.h"

int main() {

    Alg::dijkstra();

}
```

If you just want to distribute your code over several files, I don't see why the function should be declared `static`.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the 'static' keyword for local functions, with the 'static' keyword used in a class to make a function a class function and not an object function.

Remove `static` the first line of Alg.cpp and in the header file. This will allow Alg.o to contain global symbols that `main` can refer to and the linker can link.

You still need to call `Alg::dijkstra()` as was stated by @egur.

After this you may still get errors. The way you are using Alg:: is more like a `namespace` than a 'class' definition.

Answer (score 0):

Now that we have the complete declaration of your class `Arg`, it feels like the singleton design pattern could be useful:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Answer (score 0):

The key here is the `‘dijkstra’ was not declared in this scope` error.

Take your all-in-one source file and remove the `main` function. Make a new source file with this in it:

```
void dijkstra();
void output();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    dijkstra();
    output();
    return 0;
}
```

The all-in-one cpp without a `main` plus this file above should compile together and give you the same result as before with one source, as it does for me. You will get a `duplicate symbol _main` error if you forgot to remove the main from the algorithm file.

No `static` needed.

---

My answer here fails to touch on good practices on header files, that is, you would want to include those function declarations in a `.h` file. It solves the compile-time error though.

You may want to find a good book to help you through some of the machinery of C++, where program context (in a linguistic sense) can change the meaning of keywords. This can be bewildering, and it proves to be exactly that for a language with as much colorful history as C++. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for book suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll look at what you posted.