# How to call a class function in c++ without object declaration?

Tags: c++, function, class, object

I have created a function within a class. How do I call that function in int main() without declaring any object for the class?

Comment: without creating an object? or without refering the class?

Comment: not clear what you mean (you're abusing vocabulary a bit, so we can't tell); probably you want to do something that makes no sense! Please give us a **minimal**, but compiling, example of what you mean.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20362973/static-functions-in-c _maybe_ what you are looking for. But its not really clear

Comment: Maybe tell us why you want to do this...

Comment: Basically this is the problem- Print the average of three numbers entered by the user by creating a class named 'Average' having a function to calculate and print the average without creating any object of the Average class.

Comment: ... that's a bit of a stupid assignment, because it requires you to write a class where you need no class. Were these assignments maybe written by Java teachers?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using a **static member function** as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
class NAME 
{
    public:
    //define a static member function
    static void print_st() 
    {
        std::cout<<"static print_st callled"<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
   //call static member function without using an object
   NAME::print_st();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry for describing it incorrectly at first... I know how to call a function using an object of the class but I wanted to know how can i do the same thing without object declaration.

Comment: @noob You can do it for a **static** member function as shown in my edited answer/code. I have added it in my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Okay..I'll check that out

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to write your function inside the class as static. This lets you call the function without declaring an Object